org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Found shared references to a collection: com.example.BankType.translateList
Bank Entity
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bank")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BankSeq", sequenceName = "Bank_S", allocationSize = 1)
@EntityListeners({MakerCheckerListener.class})
public class Bank extends MakerCheckerTenantEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BankSeq")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BANKTYPEID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private BankType bankType;

    @Override
    public Bank cloneEntity(String checkOperation) {
        Bank cloneBank;
        try {
            cloneBank = (Bank) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        cloneBank.setId(null);
        cloneBank.setCheckOperation(checkOperation);
        return cloneBank;
    }
}

BankType Entity
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANKTYPE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BankTypeSeq", sequenceName = "BANKTYPE_S", allocationSize = 1)
@EntityListeners({AuditListener.class, MakerCheckerListener.class})
public class BankType extends MakerCheckerTenantEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BankTypeSeq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bankType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<BankTypeTranslate> translateList;

    @Override
    public Object cloneEntity(String checkOperation) {
        try {
            BankType clonedBankType = (BankType) super.clone();
            clonedBankType.setId(null);
            clonedBankType.setCheckOperation(checkOperation);
            if (this.translateList != null) {
                clonedBankType.setTranslateList(new ArrayList<>());
                for (BankTypeTranslate translate : this.translateList) {
                    BankTypeTranslate cloned = (BankTypeTranslate) translate.cloneEntity(checkOperation);
                    clonedBankType.translateList.add(cloned);
                }
            }
            return clonedBankType;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

}

BankTypeTranslate Entity
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANKTYPETRANSLATE")
@EntityListeners({MakerCheckerListener.class})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BankTypeTranslateSeq", sequenceName = "BANKTYPETRANSLATE_S", allocationSize = 1)
public class BankTypeTranslate extends MakerCheckerLanguageTenantEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BankTypeTranslateSeq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BANKTYPEID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private BankType bankType;

}

I intervene in @PreUpdate case with the MakerCheckerListener class, which I set as the Hibernate Listener for the relevant Entities.
Custom Listener class
import com.example.enums.CheckOperation;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.NoResultException;
import jakarta.persistence.PrePersist;
import jakarta.persistence.PreUpdate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class MakerCheckerListener {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public MakerCheckerListener(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(EntityManager.class);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Object entity) {
        if (entity instanceof Bank BankEntity) {
                Bank cloneBankEntity = (Bank) bankEntity.cloneEntity(CheckOperation.UPDATE.name()));
                refresh(entity);
                deleteUnCheckedBankEntity(bankEntity);
                save(cloneBankEntity);
        }
    }

    public void refresh(Object entity) {
        getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
    }

    public void deleteUnCheckedBankEntity(Bank entity) {
        Bank refEntity = null;
        try {
            String query = "from " + entity.getClass().getName() + " where checkRefId = :checkRefId and checked = false";
            refEntity = (Bank) getEntityManager().createQuery(query)
                    .setParameter("checkRefId", entity.getId()).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            refEntity = null;
        }
        if (refEntity != null){
            delete(refEntity);
        }
    }



    @Transactional
    public void save(Object entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }
}

After calling deleteUnCheckedBankEntity method, it gives
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Found shared references to a collection:  com.example.BankType.translateList
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]

error when I call the save(cloneBankEntity) method. but if I don't call the deleteUnCheckedBankEntity method, it doesn't give any error in the save method.
if I do not call deleteUnCheckedBankEntity method, I do not encounter any problems.
